# Is it possible to obtain data on the evolution of questions' views over time?

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer, data-dump, views

In the [SE data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) we can obtain a snapshot of the number of views over time. In particular, it is in the Posts table. I am looking for data on the evolution of views over time.

My question is whether there is a database or tool, available for the public, that gives the evolution of views over time. That is, optimally, a timestamp for each view. Alternatively, it may be grouped in some time interval (e.g. monthly increment in views for every given question). Any directions on obtaining even partial data on this would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You would have to download all datadumps which would give you viewcount per 3 months (roughly)

Comment: Thank you @rene. But I am wondering - how is it possible to do that? That is, in the SE data dump I can see only the most recent dump. Is there another page which agglomerates all previous data dumps?

Comment: You might want to check how far this project is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307986/do-you-have-any-data-dumps-backed-up-please-let-me-get-a-copy